# Keeping existing data in data model and just extend it with new data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

**What I do:**
I built ETL processes with power query to load data (production machine stop history) from multiple Excel files directly into PowerBI. 
On each new shift (every 8 hrs.) there is a new excel file generated by the production machine that need to be loaded to the data model too.

**How I did it:**
To do so, power query is processing all files found in a specific folder.

**The problem:**
During query refresh it need to process all the data files again and again (old files + new files).
 
If I remove the old files from the folder, power query removes the data also from the data model during the next refresh cycle.

**What I need / My question:**
A batch process copies new files into the folder while removing all the old files. 
Is there a possibility to configure powery query in a way that it **keeps the existing data inside the data model and just extend it with the data from the new files?**

**What I would like to avoid:**
I know building a database would be one solution but this requires a second system with new ETL process. But power query does already a very good job for preprocessing the data! Therefore and if possible, it would be highly appreciated if this problem could be solved directly inside power query / power bi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to shoot sparrows with a cannon gun, you could try [incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-incremental-refresh), but it's Premium feature.

In Power BI refreshing a dataset reloads it, so first it is cleared, and second - you will need all the files to re-load them and recalculate everything. If you don't want this, you have to either change your ETL to store the data outside of the report's dataset (e.g. a database would be a very good choice), or to [push the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data) from the new files only to a dataset (which I wouldn't recommend in your case).

To summarize - the best solution is to build ETL process and put the data in a datawarehouse, and then to use it as a datasource for your reports.